# How does the browser build the full URL from an href tag?

Tags: html, google-chrome, href

I am trying to build a side-bar menu.
The page I am putting the anchors into is at:

```
http://localhost/zengarden/
```

Here is the path to the file I am trying to link to:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\zengarden\221
```

When I use this href:

```
<a href="/221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a>
```

The browser (Chrome) tries to use this URL:

```
http://localhost/221/
```

If I add the parent directory to the href with a leading '/':

```
<a href="/zengarden/221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a>
```

the browser gets this URL:

```
http://localhost/xampp/
```

If I take off the leading '/':

```
<a href="zengarden/221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a>
```

the browser gets an extra 'zengarden' directory:

```
http://localhost/zengarden/zengarden/221/
```

What do I have to put into the href tag to get to where I want to go?

(by the way, I get the same results with Microsoft Edge)

Comment: try `href = "221/"`

Comment: The process you are asking about in the title is called relative URL resolution.

Comment: Tried the following:

<a href="221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a>

Result was same as the second method above:

http://localhost/xampp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, the problem was not where I expected.
The second method:

```
 <a href="/zengarden/221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a>
```

was actually working. The problem was in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\zengarden\221'. There was no 'index' file in that directory. The Apache server was kicking the browser back out to the default location instead of giving me a meaningful error message. Once I added the 'index' file I got better results.

The following method also worked:

```
 <a href="221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a>
```

I am looking at Apache logs to see if there is information that would have pointed me to the problem, but I have found nothing so far.